# Stream to Byte array conversion in Oxygene

Tags: .net, oxygene

I'm trying to find a way out with this legacy Delphi Prism application. I have never worked on Delphi Prism before.

How do I convert a Stream type to Byte Array type? Please detailed code will be really appreciated as I have no knowledge of Delphi Prism.

Basically I want to upload an Image using WCF service and want to pass the Image data as byte array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1) If you are using a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can use the [`MemoryStream.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Method directly.

Option 2) If you Are using .Net 4, copy the content of the source Stream using the [`CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to a `MemoryStream` and the call the `MemoryStream.ToArray` function.

like so

```
method TMyClass.StreamToByteArr(AStream: Stream): array of Byte;
begin
    using LStream: MemoryStream := new MemoryStream() do 
    begin
      AStream.CopyTo(LStream);
      exit(LStream.ToArray());
    end
end;
```

option 3) you are using a old verison of .Net, you can write a custom function to extract the data from the source stream and then fill a `MemoryStream`

```
method TMyClass.StreamToByteArr(AStream: Stream): array of Byte;
var 
  LBuffer: array of System.Byte;
  rbytes: System.Int32:=0;
begin
  LBuffer:=new System.Byte[1024];
  using LStream: MemoryStream := new MemoryStream() do 
  begin
    while true do 
    begin
      rbytes := AStream.Read(LBuffer, 0, LBuffer.Length);
      if rbytes>0 then
        LStream.Write(LBuffer, 0, rbytes)
      else
        break;
    end;
    exit(LStream.ToArray());
   end;
end;
```

Comment: I am using VS2008 and I guess .Net version is .Net 2.0.

I was trying to convert System.IO.Stream to MemoryStream using your solution - AStream.CopyTo(LStream), but Astream does not have the CopyTo method.

AStream := new Stream();
AStream := HtmlInputFile_UploadPath.PostedFile.InputStream;

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using a filestream (but this should work on any kind of stream):

```
class method ConsoleApp.Main;
begin
  var fs := new FileStream('SomeFileName.dat', FileMode.Open);
  var buffer := new Byte[fs.Length];
  fs.Read(buffer, 0, fs.Length);
end;
```

On the first line I create a file stream to start with, this can be your stream.
Then I create an array of byte with the length of the stream.
on the third line I copy the contents of the stream into the byte array.

Comment: Actually, no. You are writing the (empty) buffer variable to the stream. You should use fs.Read instead...